# How do I fix performance issues in SSF4:AE on the PC?

Tags: pc, super-street-fighter-iv

So I have had the game for a while now, having a positive experience with it, my PC achieved an average of 60 FPS while playing it, but now, it just reaches an average of 13 FPS, making it unplayable, I don't have any idea for the reasons of this and I am desperate for a fix since I can't find anything on the internet, does anybody have an idea for this?

I have a Radeon HD 6670 Graphics Card and a AMD FX 8120 @ 3.1 Ghz proccessor.

Comment: Does this only affect Street Fighter or does this happen in other games?

Comment: try updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: It only affects SS, I have since opened and played perfectly Watch Dogs, ACIV, Alan Wake, and some indie titles.

Comment: I just updated the drivers, still having this issue.

Comment: What does the game tell you when you run the Benchmark?